# Why won't my 2-transistor oscillator work in the real world?

Tags: transistors, oscillator

I am learning about transistors, and I've designed [this oscillator circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.05352614285189903+66+5+43%0AR+576+112+576+64+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+576+256+576+304+0%0Ar+576+112+576+176+0+4700%0Ar+576+176+576+256+0+10000%0At+352+128+352+160+1+-1+2.736375275245792+3.786771911267439+100%0AR+256+80+256+32+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+256+80+256+160+0+10000%0Ac+256+160+256+240+0+1e-8+-0.9239525721873778%0Ar+256+240+256+336+0+1000%0Ag+256+336+256+368+0%0At+400+192+400+224+0+1+-2.736375275245792+0.12644406383426943+100%0Aw+336+160+256+160+0%0Aw+352+128+464+128+0%0Aw+576+176+464+176+0%0Aw+464+240+464+176+0%0Aw+464+176+464+128+0%0Aw+464+240+416+240+0%0Aw+368+160+400+192+0%0Aw+384+240+256+240+0%0Aw+384+224+384+240+0%0Aw+416+224+416+240+0%0Ao+7+64+0+2083+5+0.0125+0+-1+0%0Ao+11+64+0+2083+5+0.025+1+-1+0%0A).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUxd1E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the simulator it works perfectly, and in my brain it makes sense, but when I try to implement the circuit in the real world it stabilizes with one side of the capacitor 0.7V above the other. I expect it to repeatedly charge and discharge the capacitor.

My reasoning:

Start w/ the capacitor discharged and all transistors are in their cutoff mode.

If the cap is discharged then it's like a short circuit, so **R1**/**R2** just form a voltage divider, which has a lower voltage than **D**, so **Q1** is not yet forward biased. This means **Q2**'s base is starved for current (which it must get from **Q1**'s collector).

As the cap charges, the voltage at **A** will eventually exceed the voltage at **D**, causing **Q1** to become forward biased. This will in turn cause current to flow from **Q1**'s collector to **Q2**'s base, forward-biasing **Q2** as well.

Now there is a 'connection' (via **Q2**'s collector/emitter) between **D** and **B**. This pulls **D** down to the same voltage as **B**, keeping **Q1** forward biased until the voltages at **A** and **B** are equal.

Now the voltages at **A**, **B**, and **D** are equal, reducing the current through the transistors to zero and returning to the original state.

---

Any information on what I may be missing or how to make my circuit work IRL would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You might want to explani why you think it should oscillate so we can point out the mistakes in that reasnong.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I linked to a simulation showing the expected behaviour.

Comment: Maybe try it with a more useful simulator like ltspice, and you will see that you are not in the initial state, I currently don't have time to show that in detail

Comment: What *may* work is adding a 100n and 10k in parallel to the base of Q2 to make it wildly oscillate somehow, though I don't think that would be the intention ;)

Comment: You state: "If the cap is discharged then it's like an open circuit...". Not so. A discharged cap is like a short circuit in the sense that any voltage you apply to it will draw infinite current, or current limited by its own internal impedance, or current limited by the impedance of the voltage source.

Comment: Your circuit can work as a oscillator https://youtu.be/2a1I1X3RV0g?t=41s

Comment: While there are similarities, that youtube oscillator is not the same circuit.  And I don't think it will work very reliably.

Comment: I agree Paul, very simple but very sensitive to ratios, stray capacitance and values. Ok for low frequency. Yet, simplicity is an illusive goal for good design. this is not a great one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, look at the circuit with the capacitor removed.  You will see that when power is applied, Q1 is turned on by the base resistors R3 and R4.  The Q1 collector current goes into the Q2 base, turning on Q2.  The Q2 collector current turns on Q1 even harder, which in turn drives Q1.  This is a positive feedback loop.  These two transistors will always be conducting, and the stable state is for both of them to be in saturation.  They are locked up.  Yes, R1 and R2 do provide some negative feedback, but not nearly enough to cancel the strong positive feedback of the cross-coupled collector to base connections.

Now add the capacitor back to the circuit.  When Q1 turns on, the emitter voltage goes more negative.  This transition is coupled to the Q2 emitter, driving it more negative, which causes Q2 to turn on as well.  This is also positive feedback.  Yes, over time current through the capacitor will diminish, but since the transistors are stable in saturation there will be no oscillation.

You need to provide negative DC feedback to stabilize the transistors in a linear operating region.  Only then will the positive feedback through the capacitor cause oscillation.  Look at your collector-to-base connections.  These are the source of your latch-up problem.

If you redraw your schematic you might find it easier to understand:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi7inN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>